# fullcalendar- unable to get date of the clicked event

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am setting up a fullcalendar which fetches events from backend and shows it. Also, users can drop events.

What I'm trying to do is to fetch the date of the clicked event. Users can click on an event and delete it. But I want to fetch the date of that event and pass the date to the backend service through an ajax call.

```
// FullCalendar v1.5
// Script modified from the "theme.html" demo file
$(document).ready(function() {

  var date = new Date();
  var d = date.getDate();
  var m = date.getMonth();
  var y = date.getFullYear();

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    theme: true,
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    editable: true,

    // add event name to title attribute on mouseover
    eventMouseover: function(event, jsEvent, view) {
      if (view.name !== 'agendaDay') {
        $(jsEvent.target).attr('title', event.title);
      }
    },
    eventDestroy: function(event, element, view) {
      alert("removing stuff");
    },
    eventClick: function(date,calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
      alert('Clicked on: ' + date.getDate()+"/"+date.getMonth()+"/"+date.getFullYear());
    //pass it to ajax function. Ajax function comes here
      var r = confirm("Delete " + calEvent.title);
      if (r === true) {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', calEvent._id);
      }
    },

    // For DEMO only
    // *************
    events: [{
      title: 'All Day Event',
      start: new Date(y, m, 1)
    }, {
      title: 'Long Event',
      start: new Date(y, m, d - 5),
      end: new Date(y, m, d - 2)
    }, {
      id: 999,
      title: 'Repeating Event',
      start: new Date(y, m, d - 3, 16, 0),
      allDay: false
    }, {
      id: 999,
      title: 'Repeating Event',
      start: new Date(y, m, d + 4, 16, 0),
      allDay: false
    }, {
      title: 'Meeting',
      start: new Date(y, m, d, 10, 30),
      allDay: false
    }, {
      title: 'Lunch',
      start: new Date(y, m, d, 12, 0),
      end: new Date(y, m, d, 14, 0),
      allDay: false
    }, {
      title: 'Birthday Party',
      start: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 19, 0),
      end: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 22, 30),
      allDay: false
    }, {
      title: 'Click for Google',
      start: new Date(y, m, 28),
      end: new Date(y, m, 29),
      url: 'http://google.com/'
    }]
  });

});
```

I tried to alert the date on event click which I'm not getting. How can I resolve this problem?

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/0o2ybsLu/)

Comment: I can use this code to get date when i click on a day. But I wanna fetch the date when I click on an event.         dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) { 
            alert('Clicked on: ' + date.getDate()+"/"+date.getMonth()+"/"+date.getFullYear());  
        }

Comment: See my solution below.  `dt` is where I am storing the date retrieved from the calendar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing the `eventClick` with :

```
eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
   var dt = calEvent.start;
    //alert('Event Clicked on : ' + dt);
    var r = confirm("Delete " + calEvent.title + "\n" + dt);
    if (r === true) {
       $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', calEvent._id);
    }
},
```

Reference : fullcalendar.io - [eventClick](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/eventClick/)

Answer (score 7):

**FullCalendar v4** now only has one parameter on the `eventClick` event:

```
var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
      eventClick: function(info) {
          var eventDate = info.event.start; 
          console.log(eventDate);
          //example output: "Wed Oct 02 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)"
    },
});
```

> Documentation: [eventClick](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventClick) | [Event Object](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object)

Comment: var eventDate = moment(info.event.start).format("YYYY-MM-DD"); 
console.log( eventDate);
Thankd you skirato i got result

Answer (score 4):

There was an error in the function `eventClick` function. You defined 4 parameters, but the function only has 3 parameters according to the [official documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/eventClick/). So the parameter you named `date` was actually the `calEvent` parameter with the `title` and `_id` attribute. I fixed your code and it is now deleting the event.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var date = new Date();
  var d = date.getDate();
  var m = date.getMonth();
  var y = date.getFullYear();

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    theme: true,
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    editable: true,

    // add event name to title attribute on mouseover
    eventMouseover: function(event, jsEvent, view) {
      if (view.name !== 'agendaDay') {
        $(jsEvent.target).attr('title', event.title);
      }
    },
    eventDestroy: function(event, element, view) {
      console.log("removing stuff");
    },
    eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
      console.log(calEvent.start.format());
      console.log(calEvent);
      alert('Clicked on: ' + calEvent.start.format());
      var r = confirm("Delete " + calEvent.title);
      if (r === true) {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', calEvent._id);
      }
    },

    // For DEMO only
    // *************
    events: [{
      title: 'All Day Event',
      start: new Date(y, m, 1)
    }, {
      title: 'Long Event',
      start: new Date(y, m, d - 5),
      end: new Date(y, m, d - 2)
    }, {
      id: 999,
      title: 'Repeating Event',
      start: new Date(y, m, d - 3, 16, 0),
      allDay: false
    }, {
      id: 999,
      title: 'Repeating Event',
      start: new Date(y, m, d + 4, 16, 0),
      allDay: false
    }, {
      title: 'Meeting',
      start: new Date(y, m, d, 10, 30),
      allDay: false
    }, {
      title: 'Lunch',
      start: new Date(y, m, d, 12, 0),
      end: new Date(y, m, d, 14, 0),
      allDay: false
    }, {
      title: 'Birthday Party',
      start: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 19, 0),
      end: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 22, 30),
      allDay: false
    }, {
      title: 'Click for Google',
      start: new Date(y, m, 28),
      end: new Date(y, m, 29),
      url: 'http://google.com/'
    }]
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.1.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.1.0/fullcalendar.min.css" />

<div id='calendar'></div>
```

Comment: How the heck did you make that runnable ?  I was trying for like 20 minutes XD   -- works perfect on jsfiddle.  Even tried switching his fiddle recources to the CDN, but didn't add `moment.js` or `jqueryui.min.js` ?

Comment: To figure out the required dependencies, I had to download the fullCalendar ZIP and check the included files. Luckily they provide the archive with all necessary dependencies. :)

Comment: +1 for the detailed answer and the sample which works. But another guy already provided the solution. (:

Comment: np, glad that you got a solution now 

Comment: `calEvent.start.format()`: This is very useful. I forgot that fullCalendar uses `moment.js`, so you can do everything with `calEvent.start`.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is

The data object has a start parameter. `date.start.getDate()`

http://jsfiddle.net/0o2ybsLu/3/

```js
// FullCalendar v1.5
// Script modified from the "theme.html" demo file
$(document).ready(function() {

  var date = new Date();
  var d = date.getDate();
  var m = date.getMonth();
  var y = date.getFullYear();

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    theme: true,
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    editable: true,

    // add event name to title attribute on mouseover
    eventMouseover: function(event, jsEvent, view) {
      if (view.name !== 'agendaDay') {
        $(jsEvent.target).attr('title', event.title);
      }
    },
    eventDestroy: function(event, element, view) {
      alert("removing stuff");
    },
    eventClick: function(date, calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
    console.log(date.start.getDate());
      alert('Clicked on: ' + date.start.getDate()+"/"+date.start.getMonth()+"/"+date.start.getFullYear());
      var r = confirm("Delete " + calEvent.title);
      if (r === true) {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', calEvent._id);
      }
    },

    // For DEMO only
    // *************
    events: [{
      title: 'All Day Event',
      start: new Date(y, m, 1)
    }, {
      title: 'Long Event',
      start: new Date(y, m, d - 5),
      end: new Date(y, m, d - 2)
    }, {
      id: 999,
      title: 'Repeating Event',
      start: new Date(y, m, d - 3, 16, 0),
      allDay: false
    }, {
      id: 999,
      title: 'Repeating Event',
      start: new Date(y, m, d + 4, 16, 0),
      allDay: false
    }, {
      title: 'Meeting',
      start: new Date(y, m, d, 10, 30),
      allDay: false
    }, {
      title: 'Lunch',
      start: new Date(y, m, d, 12, 0),
      end: new Date(y, m, d, 14, 0),
      allDay: false
    }, {
      title: 'Birthday Party',
      start: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 19, 0),
      end: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 22, 30),
      allDay: false
    }, {
      title: 'Click for Google',
      start: new Date(y, m, 28),
      end: new Date(y, m, 29),
      url: 'http://google.com/'
    }]
  });

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
      
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1510510/temp/demo/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1510510/temp/demo/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='calendar'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The runnable example is broken.  Also why I didn't include one on my sample since this calendar seems to bug out stackoverflows run code option.

Comment: Oh oki, even I'm trying to fix the code, but says jquery is not defined.

Comment: @KraangPrime So did you get what was missing?

Comment: Nope, I gave up trying to make a runnable solution for this one.  No dependencies were missing for it to be runnable -- SO just barfs when you try -- no idea why.

Comment: All the events disappear after the confirm box. I checked the fiddle you provided. @Deepak Bandi

Comment: @KraangPrime In your code are trying to fetch `date.getDate()`, replace it with `date.start.getDate()`

Answer (score 0):

```
eventClick: function(date, calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
  var eventDate = moment(date.start).format("YYYY-MM-DD"); 
  alert(eventDate);
},
```